# Commiting to github from one account, multiple emails

Tags: github

If a single GitHub account has two emails associated with it, is it possible to specify one email on some commits and the other email on other commits?

Thus, with a single account, you could perform some commits with a organizational email and other commits with a personal email.

With my .gitconfig set up like so:

```
[user]
        name = UsernameHere
        email = primary-email@email.com
```

I've attempted making commits with something like this:

```
git commit -m "misc" --author="UsernameHere <secondary-email@email.com>"
```

But the result in GitHub when I look at commits in https://github.com/UsernameHere/RepoHere/commits/master is something like:

```
UsernameHere authored and UsernameHere committed
```

Any best practice tips?

Comment: If you link to the actual commit we can have a closer look. Make a test repository if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> If a single GitHub account has two emails associated with it, is it possible to specify one email on some commits and the other email on other commits?

Yes. Make sure they're listed as "Visible in emails" in your [Email settings](https://github.com/settings/emails).

But...

> I've attempted making commits with something like this:
>
> ```
> git commit -m "misc" --author="UsernameHere <secondary-email@email.com>"
> ```
>
> But the result in GitHub... is something like:
>
> ```
> UsernameHere authored and UsernameHere committed
> ```

Committer and Author are different.

The Author is the original author of the change. The Committer is who committed the change. This is useful when someone sends you a patch and you want to make sure they're properly attributed.

In a plain `git commit` they are the same. But if you specify `--author="UsernameHere <secondary-email@email.com>"` they will be different. The Author will be UsernameHere secondary-email@email.com but the Committer will be your default name and email.

They can also diverge when you `git rebase` or `git commit --amend` or otherwise "rewrite" a commit. The Author remains the same, but the Committer changes to the user doing the "rewrite".

If you want to test multiple email addresses mapping to the same account, there is no `--committer` option. There are few reasons to change the committer, and many bad ones. Instead, you can set `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`.

```
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=secondary-email@email.com git commit -m "misc"
```

Comment: Thanks! To set both committer and author to a specific email, would the best way then be along the lines of GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=secondary-email@email.com git commit -m "misc" --author="UsernameHere <secondary-email@email.com>" ?

Comment: @relizt That will work, but only for a single command. For all commands set user.email and user.name in your config.